# How to save the decorations in monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor, decoration

I am using monaco editor in my web application. I have added BookmarkGlyphMarginClass to bookmark certain lines in monaco editor. My scenario goes like this :
In my application, on a screen I have 2 panes. The left pane contains a list and on click of any item in the left pane , the respective content opens up in the right pane which is a monaco editor. So in the right pane I had bookmarked certain lines. Next I click on second link, now the monaco editor shows contents related to the second link. Now if I again click on the first link , the lines that I had bookmarked previously is not retained. All the bookmarks have been removed. How to retain the previous bookmarks.

I'm working with normal jsp's and I'm expecting jquery side changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decorations are automatically deleted when you switch to a different editor model, so you have to store the marked line numbers/ranges somewhere and re-do the decoration creation every time your editor gets another model.